# Unable to open run window in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

trying to open the run window (with click on button or shift+F10 ) but not getting any response.

[image]

Comment: It automatically appears when you run any configuration from run window.

Comment: please send a screen shot of maniface file

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are saying you are not getting devices in the list. And with this assumption, I would say it's due to `adb` issues.

Try killing and restarting adb:

1. adb kill-server
2. adb start-server

Above command will kill the `adb` services and then start it again.

Comment: Sdk\platform-tools> adb kill-server
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Looks like your Android studio is not properly setup with needed tools. can you share screenshots of your sdk manager?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio makes a lot of files as caches and does not delete them. This can cause trouble when there is a need to make new files, so clearing caches will clear the old cache and make Android Studio faster.
Go to File --> and click invalidate catches/restart